# Discordjs : console log = length is undefnied

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the error `length is undefined`

Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const config = require("./config.json")
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

  if (err) console.log(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
  if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
    console.log("Je ne trouve pas les commandes");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} chargée!`);

  });

  fs.readdir("./events/", (error, f) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(`${f.length} events en chargement`);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` is an async function which either returns error or list of files in directory. You need to check whether error was returned or files were found, and only proceed to process returned data if no error was returned. Read more [nodejs fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback). Try this

```
  fs.readdir("./events/", (error, f) => {
    if (error) {
       console.log(error);

    } else {
       // only check length if no errors
       // otgherwise f is null and we can not call f.length
       console.log(`${f.length} events en chargement`);
    }

  })
```

Comment: Thanks, and just, now it's marked "f" is undefined" ?